# How can I make Apple Music collection Accessible to other users in my app?

Tags: ios, apple-music, apple-musickit

I want to make an iOS app that can play music from Apple Music. I tried this using Swift 4, and the result is shown in this video:

[MyApp_that_can_access_AppleMusic_VideoLink](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Uz0O7Yd5CcVc7T_KAhEnD9dl-RCldFlf/view?usp=sharing)

As the video shown, I can access my Apple Music library (using my Apple Music ID) through my own iOS app. My question is can I make the songs in my Apple Music library accessible for the other users in my app? If yes, can you tell me how?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean other users on some other device? Why would you be able to do that?  You are the subscriber who has the license to play the music.  Or do you mean you want to share a playlist to other users?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, I want to make a playlist available in my App, not my entire music library in Apple Music. So the other users of my App, in some other device, can listen to the songs that I put into that playlist when they access my profile page.